# My iphone 4s's sound settings changed by themselves

Tags: iphone

I didn't touch my phones settings, and all of a sudden (3 days ago roughly) my phone is making a sound when I get a text message, or login to my phone (entering the password), and receiving text messages etc.

Previously, my phone always vibrated for phone calls, and receiving text messages.  Sending text messages made no sound at all, nor did entering my password to unlock the phone.

How could this have happend?  My battery didn't die or anything.

And I can't seem to get those settings back anymore.

1. I have (Silent) vibrate set to ON
2. I have vibrate set to ON
3. lock sounds and keyboard sounds are both set to OFF

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the position of the upper left switch on the housing. Slide it down so that you can see the orange background. This setting mutes your iPhone. You will then hear no system sounds, only vibration.

I assume you always had that switch in that position and it accidently changed its postion to unmute.

Answer (score 0):

Try hard rebooting the phone - hold down sleep/wake and the home button until you see the red slider below:

[image]

Once the phone is powered off, give it 5 seconds, then hold down the sleep/wake until it turns back on and let it finish booting up.

Comment: what is that suppose to do?

Comment: It reboots the phone.  You said you haven't changed anything, and verified the settings haven't changed, but you're getting different behavior.  So reboot it, and see if it gets better.  If not, more diagnosis is needed.